# An electric potential is generated when a liquid moves with respect to a solid (streaming potential). Is the reverse true?

Tags: electrochemistry

Streaming potential is an electrochemical phenomenon that a that relates
electric currents with the relative movement of solid and liquid phases in contact with
each other.

So when a liquid moves past a solid a potential is generated. The equations for the values of the potential and current generated can be found [in this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_current). My question is, is the reverse true? If I applied an electrical potential difference (instead of applying a pressure difference), would a pressure difference be generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is correct. *Electrokinetic pumps* use a potential difference across an osmotic membrane, i.e. through narrow channels, the inverse of flow causing a streaming potential difference. There are other aspects of the phenomena such as *electrophoresis*, *capillary osmosis* etc.; see:

[Electrokinetic Phenomena](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrokinetic_phenomena) a

[On the Efficiency of Electrokinetic Pumping...](http://web.mit.edu/andrew3/Public/Papers/2004/Min/2004_Sensors%20and%20Actuators%20B_On%20the%20ef%EF%AC%81ciency%20of%20electrokinetic_Min.pdf)

and

[short video demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gWH-Hn4nBxM)